# Primefaces obtain inputText value in managedBean

Tags: ajax, primefaces

My question should be trivial for someone who is familiar with Primefaces but I'm just starting. My question is:
When I put inputText component to my web page like this:

```
<h:form id="formularz">
    <p:inputText id="workyears" value="#{appointentBean.year}" style="width: 40px;"/>
<h:form>
```

I would like to retrieve the inputed text directly from appointentBean. I mean I would like to create another method in appointentBean that will process inputed text so I need inputed text to be placed in referenced field year immediately. In another worlds I need my field year in appointentBean to be automaticaly updated while someone put text in inputText component. Something like submit? I hope you understand what I mean.

Here is my managedBean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@SessionScoped
public class appointentBean{

    private int year;

public int getYear() {
    return year;
}

public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}

    //Here I will put another method that will be operate on year value
}
```

Comment: By `my field year in appointentBean to be automaticaly updated while someone put text in inputText component` you mean an ajax interaction with keypress event to call your method?

Comment: would like to retrieve inputed text directly `--->` Is this autocomplete you talking about?.  Automatically updated?

Comment: Yes I will use commandButton to call my method

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using events like this ([read more](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajaxifyKeyEvents.jsf)):

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputText value="#{viewMBean.hello}">
        <p:ajax event="keyup" update="hello" process="@this" />  
    </p:inputText>

    <h:outputText id="hello" value="#{viewMBean.hello}" />
</h:form>
```

Here is the viewMBean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ViewMBean implements Serializable {

    private String hello;

    public String getHello() {
        return hello;
    }

    public void setHello(String hello) {
        this.hello = hello;
    }

}
```

PS: Welcome to Primefaces!!